# Configure JNDI names with Open EJB

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, openejb

I'm trying to (unit) test my EJB class without having to startup my websphere environment. Now I'm using [Open EJB](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/jndi-names.html), but there are some issues with resolving the JNDI Names for other EJBs that are used within my EJB... and there is no way for me to inject mocked classes from my test right now.

**Getting the InitialContext**

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");
properties.setProperty("log4j.category.OpenEJB.options ", "debug");
properties.setProperty("log4j.category.OpenEJB.startup ", "debug");
properties.setProperty("log4j.category.OpenEJB.startup.config ", "debug");
properties.setProperty("MyOwnDatasource.JdbcDriver ", "com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
properties.setProperty("MyOwnDataSource.JdbcUrl ", "jdbc:as400:MYHOSTNAME;database name=MYDATABASE;libraries=MYDEFAULTTABLE");
ic = new InitialContext(properties);
```

Inside my class under test there is a lookup for `java:comp/env/ejb/PrefixEjbNameLocalHome` and I can not set Open EJB to generate JNDI names in that format.

**Additional Property for JNDI name format**

I tried setting the formatting rule like this:

```
properties.setProperty("openejb.jndiname.format ", "comp/env/ejb/{interfaceClass}");
```

**Properties aren't used?**

Also the logging configuration isn't used. I'm only seeing *INFO* and *WARN* messages from Open EJB, although I set `log4j.category.OpenEJB.*` and the like to *DEBUG* or *TRACE*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the "java:" part that is messing up your test case.  Basically Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY and "java:" are mutually exclusive.  The InitialContext class has a special understanding of "java:" or any "foo:" lookups and if they are at the beginning of the name it will *not* use INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY you specified.  A somewhat frustrating part of JNDI.

If you lookup the name exactly as printed in the log, it will work.  So for example this log message:

```
INFO - Jndi(name=WidgetBeanRemote) --> Ejb(deployment-id=WidgetBean)
```

Then in code:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");
// set any other properties you want
Context context = new InitialContext(p);

Object o = context.lookup("WidgetBeanRemote");
```

Comment: wow thanks. I've been battling with this for some time. Especially to find a name that can be looked up both when testing with openEjb and deploying on Tomee.