# Open EJB embeded container can not find the JNDI Name

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, junit4, openejb

I tried to use `OpenEJB` for my `EJB` `Timer` task `Unit test`. I get an error saying that it can't find the `JNDI` name.

```
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.client.LocalInitialContextFactory");


  IService bean;
  try {
        Context context = new InitialContext(props);
        bean = (IService) context.lookup("java:global/My-App/SingleOccurrenceServiceBean");

       assertNotNull(bean);

  } catch (NamingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

And below is the log out put.

```
Apache OpenEJB 3.1.4    build: 20101112-03:32
http://openejb.apache.org/
INFO - openejb.home = D:\workspace\task\My-App
INFO - openejb.base = D:\workspace\task\My-App
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Security Service, type=SecurityService, provider-id=Default Security Service)
INFO - Configuring Service(id=Default Transaction Manager, type=TransactionManager, provider-id=Default Transaction Manager)
INFO - Configuring enterprise application: classpath.ear
INFO - Enterprise application "classpath.ear" loaded.
INFO - Assembling app: classpath.ear
INFO - Deployed Application(path=classpath.ear)
 javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "global/My-App/SingleOccurrenceServiceBean" not found.
```

Here is the Maven dependency.

```
 <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
 <artifactId>openejb-core</artifactId>
 version>3.1.4</version>
```

What could be the error?

---

### UPDATE

```
@Remote
public interface IService {

 public void initializeTimer(Date firstDate, long timeout, String info) throws RemoteException;

 void cancelTimer(String timerName) throws RemoteException;

 /**
   * doService call when the EJBTimer timeout. And it start the service intend to do.
   * @param timer
  */
     @Timeout
 public void doService(Timer timer);


}





@Stateless
public class SingleOccurrenceServiceBean implements IService{

    @Override
public void initializeTimer(Date firstDate, long timeout, String info) throws RemoteException {
    try {
        timerService.createTimer(firstDate, info); 

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.fatal("Exception create timer : "+ e.toString()); 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void cancelTimer(String timerName) throws RemoteException {
    // do nothing as this timer is a single-event-timer
}


@Override
@Timeout
public void doService(Timer timer) {
    log.debug("Read data from DB");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this. I had to add `ejb-jar.xml` file in to `resources`>`META-INF`. But the file contains nothing except

```
<ejb-jar/>
```

and got a help from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4052898/why-datasource-is-not-found-in-jndi-after-injection-from-jndi-properties)

Special Thank to Camilo for helping me so far.

Comment: ejb-jar.xml should be available in both src/main/resources/META-INF and src/test/resources/META-INF

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the JNDI name you're looking up doesn't exist, in OpenEJB the default JNDI name for an EJB should be:

```
{deploymentId}{interfaceType.annotationName}
```

and you don't need the `java:` , check [the docs](http://tomee.apache.org/jndi-names.html), and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865356/configure-jndi-names-with-open-ejb).

**UPDATE**

Try

```
...bean = (IService) context.lookup("SingleOccurrenceServiceBeanRemote");...
```

Comment: Do I need use openejb-jar.xml? I did not do anything just add the open ejb dependency and run the unit test. Is it correct? I did not deploy or did nothing. Just run the unit test class.

Comment: please provide your `SingleOccurrenceServiceBean` and `IService` code and complete log output if posible

Comment: Updated the question with Bean class and Interface.

Comment: Sorry, issue still persist.    jvax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name "SingleOccurrenceServiceBeanRemote" not found.